# Group associative array elements by values and preserve original keys as new values in each group

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, preserve

I want to be able to group `Associative Arrays` with their `keys. So far I'm lost of what syntax to use.

As of now, I have thus code,

```
$associativeArray = array("Ripe Mango"=>"Yellow", "Strawberry"=>"Red", "Lemon"=>"Yellow");
groupByColor($associativeArray);

function groupByColor($groupedArray)
{
  return $groupedArray;
}
```

My goal is to return the `array` while having it grouped, the ideal result will be like this;

`["Yellow"=>["Ripe Mango", "Lemon"], "Red"=>["Strawberry"]]`

Any hints on what method to use?

Comment: You could `foreach` through your array and add to a new array with the color as key.

Comment: The easiest way is to run through the input array (using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) and iteratively build the desired output array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside function do [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php

$associativeArray = array("Ripe Mango"=>"Yellow", "Strawberry"=>"Red", "Lemon"=>"Yellow");

function groupByColor($associativeArray){
    $final_array = [];
    foreach($associativeArray as $key=>$val){
        $final_array[$val][] = $key;
    }

   return $final_array;  
}
print_r(groupByColor($associativeArray));
```

Output:- https://eval.in/933011

***Note:- you can assign `groupByColor($associativeArray)` returned array to a new variable and print that variable like below:-***

```
$color_array = groupByColor($associativeArray);
print_r($color_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function to trait every value of the array:

```
<?php
$array = ["Ripe Mango"=>"Yellow", "Strawberry"=>"Red", "Lemon"=>"Yellow"];
$result = [];
array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[$value][] = $key;
});

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by processing each key and convert value to key and check if exist then append to it else create it

```
function groupByColor ($groupedArray) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($groupedArray as $key=>$val) {
    if (array_key_exists($val, $result)) {
      $result[$val][] = $key;
    } else {
      $result[$val] = array();
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` through your array and add to a new array with the color as key:

```
<?php
$associativeArray = array("Ripe Mango"=>"Yellow", "Strawberry"=>"Red", "Lemon"=>"Yellow");
$new = groupByColor($associativeArray);
var_dump($new);

function groupByColor($groupedArray)
{
    foreach ( $groupedArray as $key => $color ) {
        $tmp[$color][] = $key;
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know how to do it would be with a loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$associativeArray = array("Ripe Mango"=>"Yellow", "Strawberry"=>"Red", "Lemon"=>"Yellow");

$data = groupByColor($associativeArray);
print_r($data);

function groupByColor($groupedArray)
{
    foreach ($groupedArray as $key => $value) {
        $final[$value][] = $key;
     } 

    return $final;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be elegantly performed with [a body-less foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030747/2943403).

In the loop signature, declare the values as `$v`, then use square brace syntax to push elements into their appropriate groups.  The first level is identified by the declared `$v` value and the "original key" will be pushed as a new entry into the group's indexed subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oDCon))

```
$array = [
    "Ripe Mango" => "Yellow",
    "Strawberry" => "Red",
    "Lemon" => "Yellow"
];
$result = [];

foreach ($array as $result[$v][] => $v);

var_export($result);
```

---

Using functional iteration just doesn't have the same elegance. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VcjLS))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($array),
        fn($result, $key) => array_merge_recursive($result, [$array[$key] => [$key]]),
        []
    )
);
```