# Within a foreach() expression, is the value defined before or after the key?

Tags: php, foreach, key, variable-assignment, key-value

In a classic [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop after the word `as`, is it possible to use the `key` variable as part of the `value` variable or vice versa?

<sub>* after more than a decade of PHP development, this possibility only just now occurred to me to investigate.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `foreach()` always assigns the `value` variable before assigning the `key` variable. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iVm1u))

This seems a little counterintuitive because `$v` visually appears to be declared *after* it is access by `key` declaration.

This means you can safely use:

```
$array = ['a', 'b'];
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $result["prefix_$v"] => $v);
var_export($result);
```

to produce:

```
array (
  'prefix_a' => 0,
  'prefix_b' => 1,
)
```

The newly generated array has prefixed keys based on the original values and the original indexes become the new values.

Without the `prefix_` prepended to the string, the action is effectively the same as `array_flip()`.

---

Reversing the assignments so that the `value` variable receives the `key` does not work as intended. You might hope to generate `["prefix_0", "prefix_1"]` but it does not and it also generates Notices/Warnings due to trying to access an undeclared variable. (The complaint is only on the first iteration because after the first iteration, `$k` is declared -- it is the previous iteration's key.)

```
$array = ['a', 'b'];
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $result["prefix_$k"]);
// not defined on first iteration -------^^
var_export($result);
```

**Bad** Output:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $k in /in/iVm1u on line 6
array (
  'prefix_' => 'a',
  'prefix_0' => 'b',
)
```

---

For additional context, I'll offer one more working example that generates a multi-dimensional array using the value to determine the array keys in the output array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hkhFD))

```
$array = [2, 3, 5];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $result[$v * $v][$v] => $v);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  4 => 
  array (
    2 => 0,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    3 => 1,
  ),
  25 => 
  array (
    5 => 2,
  ),
)
```

Comment: May be of note, that this also works with `list()` - https://3v4l.org/JCSIi

Comment: Yes, originality I had a more complex example using array destructuring like that, but in the end I decided to try to produce the simplest possible demonstration to reduce confusion.  That technique is kind of like a fusion of `array_flip()` and `array_column()`.