# Order of execution for functions on either side of the assignment operator

Tags: php, operator-precedence, php-8, order-of-execution

I want to implement a function

```
$input = ['key1', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2'];
// $output = ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'];
$output=[];
do {
    $output[current($input)] = next($input);
} while (next($input));
```

I wrote this code intuitively, but when I reviewed this code today, I pondered if this might be a bug.

I assumed the output should be something like this:

```
['value1'=>'value1','value2'=>'value2']
```

because `next()` takes precedence over `current()`, but this function works fine in PHP8.

Why is this? Isn't assignment from right to left?

Comment: You haven't explained what output you're getting in whatever version of PHP you think is problematic, or what version of PHP you think has a bug. The problem with code like this is that you might think it's elegant and clever, but clearly it's purpose is not clear to PHP. Some poor soul who comes along after you may not understand it either. Always go for clarity. Always.

Comment: I tried this in [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/8h36m) It produced the same output in every PHP version back as far as 5.4. PHP5.3 failed because it didn't like the shortform array notation. I think the problem is in your head.

Comment: Sorry, there is a problem with my expression. What I mean is not which version of php will have different output, but I think that the assignment operator is operated from right to left, so it should execute next before executing current, but actually In the operation, the current is first and then the next (at least in php8), this is my doubt, why the operation logic is from right to left, but the order of execution is not like this @TangentiallyPerpendicular

I've changed the logic to the following, just out of curiosity

$key = current($input);
$output[$key] = next($input);

Comment: Kind of, sort of on this topic: [Within a foreach() expression, is the value defined before or after the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71030746/2943403)

Comment: Concise alternatives: [`array_column(array_chunk($input, 2), 1, 0)`](https://3v4l.org/Z46an) and to destroy the keys: [`array_column(array_chunk($input, 2), 1, 1)`](https://3v4l.org/Kfu3V)

Answer (score 2):

The associativity is from left to right for `=` *for your case*. You can cross check this with the below snippet where `t1` gets printed first instead of `t2`.

```
<?php

$output=[];

$output[test('t1')] = test('t2');

function test($str){
    echo $str,PHP_EOL;
    return rand(10, 100);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/OlQnE)

Hence, your output is `[ 'key1' => 'value1','key2' => 'value2']` because `current()` gives `key1` and `next()` advances the internal array pointer and returns the element value which is `value1` and the same gets repeated over until the array is looped completely.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my question about who executes first, maybe I mixed up the order of assignment and the order of execution
Secondly, I'm sorry, I have a problem with the description. The result I want is ['key'=>'value'], but what I mentioned in the title is just that I think the execution result of this code should be ['value'=> 'value'] @mickmackusa

Comment: @caijw Fair enough. I removed the irrelevant part.